# Calculate the average value for each day of the week in time series using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, average, weekday

Current DataFrame is as follows-

```html
import datetime
#Adding Day,Weekday Field in dataframe
df1['day']=df1['timestamp'].dt.weekday
df1['DOW'] = df1['timestamp'].dt.day_name()
df1.info()
df1.head()
```

I want to add Avg Value for "perf_data.load5" with Day of Week in current dataframe as new column as Avg_DOW.

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqJvB.png)

I tried adding new column but it is showing NAN values.

```html
df1['avg_dow']=df1[['perf_data.load5','DOW']].groupby(('DOW'),sort=False).mean()
df1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm8qd.png)

But While using code in which I don't add new column to dataframe it is working fine.

Please Suggest how to add Avg_DOW column in the existing dataframe.

Thank You in Advance.

```html
df1[['perf_data.load5','DOW']].groupby(('DOW'),sort=False).mean()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R14jm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code working fine and suffice the need.

```html
df.join(df.groupby(['hour', 'weekday'])['value'].mean(), on=['hour','weekday'], rsuffix='_avg')
```

For more details regarding this,pls visit-[enter link description here](https://github.com/srivatsan88/End-to-End-Time-Series/blob/master/Anomaly_Detection_using_Isolation_Forest_Feature_Engineering.ipynb)